# When can you be sure to have a spanning set for the vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Here is the problem:

Let $K$ be a field with $q$ elements and $V$ be a vector space over $K$. If you'd collect vectors from $V$ (and never took the same one twice) what is the minimum amount of elements which you could be sure to be a spanning set(a generator set) for $V$?

My reasoning is as follows:

There must be $q^n$ vectors in $V$, since that is the amount of different combinations of $q$ elements in n value slots (an n-dimensional vector) So of course $q^n$ must be a spanning set. If $(q^n) - 1$ was not a spanning set that would mean that $q^n$ was a minimal spanning set and therefore a base of $V$. But that is impossible since a base of any $n-$dimensional vectorspace contains n elements. Therefore $(q^n)-1$ is a spanning set as well. This applies to $(q^n) -2$ and so on.. Until - we reach $n$ vectors. Therefore every set of vectors containg between $q^n$ and $n$ elements must be a spanning set and therefore the minimal amount of elements you have to collect to have a spanning set for sure is $n$.

But that reasoning contradicts the solution of the problem, which is $(q^n-1) +1. $

Can anyone help me understand my error and the solution?

Looking forward very much to your responses!

Answer (score 1):

A set $A$ of vectors is not a generator set if there is a linear subspace $L\leq V$ such that $A\subset L$. An $n-1$-dimensional subspace has $q^{n-1}$ elements so you have to have at least $q^{n-1}+1$ vectors.

Answer (score 0):

We can see the flaw in your reasoning as follows. Suppose $F=\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$ and $n=2$. Then $A=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)\}$ spans $F$ and $B=\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$ does not span $F$. But this does not mean that $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)\}$ is a minimal spanning set for $F$ because $C=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ is a smaller spanning set. We just happened to remove the wrong element from $A$.

As @szlev has pointed out above, the solution given also appears to be wrong because for $n=2$ we must choose at least $q+1$ vectors to be sure of a spanning set. This is because a set of $q$ vectors could all be scalar multiples of one another and so lie in the same one-dimensional sub-space.